# Why is my external hard-drive is not appearing (most of the time)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, usb, external-disk

I recently bought an external hard-drive, Western Digital 4GB, and I have a MacBook-pro 2015 (15inch).

When I received the hard-drive, it worked like a dream, I just re-formatted it to apple's file system (non-encrypted). One time the USB cable got accidentally knocked out the left side, and then from then on, if I plugged the hard-drive in the left USB, it wouldn't show up. So I started using the right side USB, no problem. And then a week later, the same thing happened, accidentally knocked the cable out, and from then on, it wouldn't show up.

I have an external USB hub (USB powered), and now that is the only way I can use the external drive, (**most** of the time), it usually appears with a 1/5 chance, but once appeared, it is stable. This is not due to the USB hub, as I have two other 4TB hard-drives in a 5 bay 3.5" enclosure.

How can I remedy this problem? The drive does not show up in the Disk Utility program, nor does it show up under `USB` in the System Information program, nor does it show up with `$ diskutil list`, nor does in show up in `/Volumes`. I thought it might be a cache problem, maybe Mac does some caching of hard-drives used, etc.., so I removed the cache's from `/Library` and `/System`.

I'm a programmer, so any command-line solutions are very welcome.

Comment: It's possible that knocking out the USB plugs has damaged the sockets within the MacBook, and/or, perhaps, the USB plug itself. Try your external drive with another USB cable in another computer, and see whether the drive shows up as it should.

Comment: Possible, but I believe unlikely as all other USB devices function with no problem, using my colleagues MacBook-pro (same spec except for CPU and RAM), the right USB didn't work, but the left did. The USB cable supplied has a proprietary connector, so I will have to order a new cable to assert whether this is the problem...